# php finding closest space char after mb_substr()

Tags: php, string, utf-8, mbstring

i need to cut the string approximately at 160 characters, but i want to do the cut off through closest space character. The task is worsened by working UTF-8 font (`mb_` function). My code is following:

```
<?php
function mb_strrev($str, $encoding='UTF-8'){

   return mb_convert_encoding( strrev( mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-16BE', $encoding) ),

$encoding, 'UTF-16LE');
}

$in = mb_strpos(mb_strrev(trim(mb_substr($mysring, 0, 165))), ' ');

$new = mb_substr(mb_strrev(trim(mb_substr($mysring, 0, 165))), $in, 165);

mb_strrev($new);
?>
```

Does anyone know more elegant way?

Comment: UTF-8 is not a font, it's an *encoding*.

Comment: @deceze, indeed, i use a font encoded in utf8

Comment: No you're not, you're working with *strings* encoded in UTF-8. :-P

Comment: @deceze, oh, my, it's too hard for macaque at my awatar ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do something like this:

```
<?php  
function approx_len($str,$len) {  
$x = explode(" ",$str);  
$y = count($x);  
$newlen = '';  
for ($i = 0; $i < $y; $i++) {  
$this_x = $x[$i]. ' ';  
if (strlen($newlen.$this_x) > $len) $i = $y;  
else $newlen = $newlen.$this_x;  
}  
return $newlen;  
}  
$x = approx_len("aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa aaaaa",160);  
echo $x;  
echo '<br />';  
echo strlen($x);  
//returns 156
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Found [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php#90724), maybe it's more elegent to you.

Comment: With some modifications, the function at the URL you gave was more elegant than the solution I have been using. Thank you!